# How to remove the gap between border and background image

Tags: html, css

Why do I get the gap between the border and background:

[image]

Comment: please provide your html and css code in order to help

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:block` to the image and it will look OK.

**without `display:block`**

```css
.wrapper {
  background:red;  
}

img {
  border:1px solid yellow;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIF3E.jpg" />
</div>
```

**with `display:block`**

```css
.wrapper {
  background:red;  
}

img {
  border:1px solid yellow;  
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIF3E.jpg" />
</div>
```